# How to really end with the sessions

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm using `Session` to keep my `login`. I also, test it on every `page_load` i have, like this:

```
if (Session["login"] != null)
{
    LbLogado.Text = "";
    LbLogado.Text += "Logado Com: " + Session["login"].ToString();
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
}
```

I also have a button `exit`, and this is the event:

```
Session.Clear();
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```

When I click on the exit button,I want to end with every `session` I have.
What is happening is, when I exit, and click on the browser to go back to the previous webpage it return normal to the page, but I want to redirect to the `login.aspx` page, because there is no `sessions` active.
I found some articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158086/session-not-ending-in-asp-net) . But it's not my point.

Comment: [Session.Abandon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx)

Comment: Have you looked at Session.Abandon - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx - since you want to end every session - also the back action doesn't really really issue a /get if you hit back and refresh you probably will get expected behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx):

> Once the Abandon method is called, the current session is no longer valid and a new session can be started. Abandon causes the End event to be raised. A new Start event will be raised on the next request.

Comment: When I click to go back to the previous page, it loads the page normal, but if I try to interact with the webpage, it returs me to the login page. Is possible to instead it shows the page when I click to  back to previous page, it test the `session` and go right to the login.aspx ? Or it's the only way to be done ?

Comment: The verification `(Session["login"] != null) { .... } else { Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx"); }` aren't doing that?

Comment: Only when I try to interact with the webpage (Click on a link). But when I click to go back to the previous page, it does not go the `page_load` event. But I guess it's normal... Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it's the browser behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

> This should work in your case:

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```